# functions used by R function nlminb()

Tags: r, gradient-descent, nonlinear-optimization

I was using the nlminb() function for optimization in R software.

function takes an optional argument "gradient" that takes the same arguments as objective function to be optimized and evaluates the gradient of objective at its first argument. Must return a vector as long as the length of parameter set.

I want to know which method is used by the nlminb() function to find the gradient of the objective function if the gradient function is not given to the arguments?

I have used the nlminb() function for optimization without giving the "gradient" argument.

Comment: Basically that argument allows you to specify a gradient function when there exists an analytical one which could be more efficient. Otherwhise (as Ben answer exposes clearly) a numerical solution is attemped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I suspected, the answer is "finite differences", but it's not easy to find.  If you dig deep enough you find the functions DRMNF (for unbounded optimization: DRMNFB is the analogous function for bounded optimization) from the Port library, and the comment [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/src/portsrc.f#L1599-L1603)

```
      SUBROUTINE DRMNF(D, FX, IV, LIV, LV, N, V, X)
C
C  ***  ITERATION DRIVER FOR  DMNF...
C  ***  MINIMIZE GENERAL UNCONSTRAINED OBJECTIVE FUNCTION USING
C  ***  FINITE-DIFFERENCE GRADIENTS AND SECANT HESSIAN APPROXIMATIONS.
```

and [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/src/portsrc.f#L1622-L1625):

```
C     [...]   INSTEAD OF CALLING CALCG TO OBTAIN THE
C     GRADIENT OF THE OBJECTIVE FUNCTION AT X, DRMNF CALLS DS7GRD,
C     WHICH COMPUTES AN APPROXIMATION TO THE GRADIENT BY FINITE
C     (FORWARD AND CENTRAL) DIFFERENCES USING THE METHOD OF REF. 1.
```

Ref 1 is Stewart, G. W. 1967. “A Modification of Davidon’s Minimization Method to Accept Difference Approximations of Derivatives.” Journal of the ACM 14 (1): 72–83. https://doi.org/10.1145/321371.321377.